# indented bullet point after R chunk in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way to continue a list with an indented bullet point following an R chunk in Rmarkdown (with HTML output)?  When I try this:

````
## R Markdown

1. First item in list
    + run this R code:  
    ```{r cars}
    # code...
    ```
    + Continuing a list at the same level after an R chunk works.
2. Second item
```{r}
# example code
```
    + Continuing a list at an increased level of indentation doesn't work.
````

I get this:
[image]

Comment: Why not indent the second code chunk? It renders as I believe you want if you do.

Comment: @KevinArseneau -- Would make a great answer. That suggestion will indeed continue the list at the proper indentation.

Comment: In general the reason that I want to be able to increase the indent following a code chunk is so that I can make comments about the code chunk itself. So what I really want is bullet points that are indented more than the code chunk.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should indent any code block relative to the list item it belongs to, i.e. both the first and the second code block:

````
## R Markdown

1. First item in list
    + run this R code:  
        ```{r cars}
        # code...
        ```
        and look at the output
    + Continuing a list at the same level after an R chunk works.
2. Second item
    ```{r}
    # example code
    ```
    + Continuing a list at an increased level of indentation does work.
````

this way continuing the list item after the code block works in addition to handling new list items properly:

[image]